# Change the forecolor of labels with single timer (can it be ?)

Tags: c#

I have a form with 5 labels in it. Can I change the `ForeColor` of these labels with 1 Timer?

For example, when I want to change the forecolor of one of the labels, I have to write:

```
Button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

This only affects one form. Do I have to set 1 timer for each label? This becomes cumbersome if I have 30 labels, because then I have to write 30 different timers.

Also, is it possible to have a sound when a timer starts?

Comment: 1 interval for timer with 1 method of label color changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, on your timer tick event (I'm assuming the standard winforms timer control), just set the color for all labels:

```
label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
label2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
label3.ForeColor = Color.Red;
// etc.
```

Or if all your label components are direct descendants of one control (for example, your form):

```
foreach(var label in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
  label.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

To play a system sound, just add:

```
System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
```

`Asterisk` can be `Beep`, `Exclamation`, `Hand` or `Question` for the standard windows system sounds ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.systemsounds(v=vs.110).aspx)).

If you want to play a custom sound, you can use [System.Media.SoundPlayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var mySound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\path\to\yoursoundfile.wav");
mySound.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//5 labels
```

`int i = 0;
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    System.Console.Beep();
                    i++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    label2.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
                    System.Console.Beep();
                    i++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    label3.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                    System.Console.Beep();
                    i++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    label4.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    System.Console.Beep();
                    i++;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    label5.ForeColor = Color.Pink;
                    System.Console.Beep();
                    i++;
                    break;
            }
        }`